# In systemverilog, how to detect operand attribute (signed or unsigned) in text macro (define)?

Tags: attributes, system-verilog

I am writing a piece of verilog code that negate a value. I expect if operand is signed, return its negative value and it is unsigned, return '1'.
Here is my code,

```
`define negation (a) ((a<0 || -a<0 || (a-1)<0) ? -a : 1)
```

Is there any fancy way to detect operand attributes?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in attribute to check that an operand is signed. You could write your own attribute

```
let issigned(v) = (v|~v)<0;
```

Then use

```
let negation(a) = issigned(a) ? -a : 1;
```

You could do this with a text macro, but `let` is better to catch mistakes.

Comment: One more question, is 'let' construct synthesizable? When I try with "Jan 17, 2019 DC", it showed an error of "The construct 'let' is not supported in synthesis. (VER-700)"

Comment: The `let` construct should be synthesisable if the expression it expands to is synthesizable. Whether your tool supports it is another question.